# Finding the number of rendered child components in react test using enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I've spent all day diving into the Enzyme docs and starting to get the hang of the basics.

I'm looping through some data in my Redux store to render these nested `<BudgetWidgetCard />` components into my parent component and want to ensure that `X` of them are getting rendered to the page.

## Component Example

```
  <div>
    <main className="col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2 pt-3">
      <h1 name='main-header-title'>{metaProperties.pageTitle}</h1>
      {budgetWidgets.map((widget, i) => {
        return <BudgetWidgetCard className='budget-widget' title={widget} key={i} state={this.props} />
      })}
</main>
</div>
```

## Test Approach

```
  it('+++renders the budget widget items correctly', () => {
      console.log(wrapper.children().children().filter('budget-widget').length)
      console.log(wrapper.find(<BudgetWidgetCard />).forEach(child => {
        console.log(child.text())
      }))
    })
```

I don't like the idea of calling children().children()... seems tightly coupled, but maybe that is the approach to go. My end goal is to simplistically state that the shallow render of `componentA` has `X` number of `<BudgetWidgetCards />`

I get the following output:

```
Review Current Budget<BudgetWidgetCard /><BudgetWidgetCard /><BudgetWidgetCard /><BudgetWidgetCard />Add A New Budget Item<ReduxForm /><BudgetTable />
```

When using the following:

```
  wrapper.children().forEach(child=> {
    console.log(child.text())
  })
```

## Test File

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
// import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import { MemoryRouter as Router, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { configureStore } from '../src/configuration/store';
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

/**
BUDGET COMPONENTS
**/
import Budget from '../src/Budget/components/Budget';
import BudgetWidgetCard from '../src/Budget/components/Budget';

let mainHeaderTitle = 'Review Current Budget';
const store = configureStore();
const wrapper = shallow(<Budget />);

// Snapshot for Budget React Component
describe('>>>B U D G E T --- Snapshot',()=>{
  it('+++capturing Snapshot of Budget', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<Budget />);
      expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    })
});

describe('>>>B U D G E T --- Elements Getting Rendered Correctly',()=>{
  it('+++correct title is getting rendered as header', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find('h1[name="main-header-title"]').text()).toEqual(mainHeaderTitle);
    })

  it('+++renders the budget widget items correctly', () => {
      expect(wrapper.children().find(BudgetWidgetCard).length).toE‌​qual(4)
    })
});
```

Answer (score 12):

If you import the component you expect to be rendered x times you can do this:

```
expect(wrapper.find(BudgetWidgetCard)).to.have.length(x);
```

http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html

Comment: Hm. I'm using Jest as well, but maybe I'm still doing this wrong.
expect(wrapper.find(BudgetWidgetCard).length).toEqual(4)

Comment: The above length is finding 0

Comment: Then your wrapper is not finding any instances of BudgetWidgetCard

Comment: I'm seeing them in my snapshot under props: Object { "children" :

Comment: expect(wrapper.find(BudgetWidgetCard)).to.have.length(x);

Comment: expect(wrapper.children().find(BudgetWidgetCard).length).toEqual(4)
still doesn't work

Comment: I've updated the OP to explain. Also, as I'm using Jest, .to.have.length isn't defined

Comment: Why are you doing wrapper.children()?

Comment: Could you post your whole test file so I can see why?

Comment: Also, make sure to do .find(BudgetWidgetCard) not . find(<BudgetWidgetCard/>)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162939/discussion-between-ryan-hack-and-galupuf).

Comment: PS. using `console.log(wrapper.debug())` will help you no end when trying to figure out what has actually been rendered into the test, rather than multiple logs of children etc. Especially helpful to spot every time I stupidly forget about an HOC in a shallow rendered test!

Answer (score 4):

I will address the title of the question and not the body, since others addressed the specific scenario described here already in great details, but I wish to focus on the broader aspect of the question, which is to count `children`:

#### [Enzyme `children()`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/children.html) method allows that.

> Returns a new wrapper with all of the children of the node(s) in the current wrapper. Optionally, a selector can be provided and it will filter the children by this selector

#### For example:

```js
const wrapper = mount(<ToDoList items={items} />);
expect(wrapper.children()).to.have.length(items.length);
```

Assuming `<ToDoList>` component returns an element with varying number of children inside it.

Answer (score 3):

Simply call **`.length`** on the `ReactWrapper` instance.

```
wrapper.find('button.nice').length
```

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ReactWrapper/length.md

Answer (score 1):

In additional to all sayed above.

There are [expected behavior, that ".find" has more length than expected items](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/836)

To find length, developers in issue recommended to use

```
wrapper.find('button.nice').hostNodes()
```

But only solution worked for me is

```
wrapper.find('button.nice').children()
```